# Outputting a Returned pair Without a Temporary

Tags: c++, output, std-pair, temporary, tie

Let's say that I have a function: `pair<int, int> foo()` I want to directly output both elements of this *without* using a temporary.

Is there a way that I can output this, or maybe convert it into a string to output? Could I perhaps use `tie` to do this?

Here's what I'm trying to do *with* the temporary:

```
const auto temporary = foo();

cout << temporary.first << ' ' << temporary.second << endl;
```

Comment: If you are asking for performance reasons, this is a probably a dead end. If you are asking for stylistic reasons, I have a hard time imagining what it would look like.

Comment: I don't see how you could avoid a temporary.  You could scope it though so you don't pollute the scope with a one time use name, i.e. `{ const auto temporary = foo();

cout << temporary.first << ' ' << temporary.second << endl; }`

Comment: @NathanOliver: In which case we should shove it into its own function :-)

Comment: You can create a function such that you will be able to use `cout << foo()` but that's not going to save you a temporary. It's not clear to me what your objective is.

Comment: `temporary` is not a temporary, it's an automatic variable. If you do NOT give a name to the return value object, then that object is a temporary.  It's not really clear to me what you are asking; are you trying to mean that you want to output the 2 pair members without declaring a named variable to hold the return value?

Comment: @M.M I just wanted to directly output the return. It looks like that's not doable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can't write that function without using a non-temporary. If you really need to, you should probably change the structure of your code. Technically, you could also use a global variable (although I strongly do not recommend this). I don't think `tie` would work for what you want it for either.

Answer (score 3):

In c++17 standard, you can use [structured binding declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding)

```
std::pair<int, int> get_pair()
{
    return {10, 20};
}

int main()
{
    auto [x, y] = get_pair();
    std::cout << x << " " << y << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that there is an implicit temporary associated with the structured binding (and x and y refer to members of it)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a small class that wraps the `std::pair`, and enable output streams to print it via `operator<<`:

```
template<typename PairT>
struct printable {
    const PairT& p;
    printable(const PairT& p)
        :    p{p}
    {}
};

template<typename CharT, typename PairT>
std::basic_ostream<CharT>& operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharT>& out, const printable<PairT>& pair) {
    out << pair.p.first << ' ' << pair.p.second;
    return out;
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
auto foo() {
    return std::pair<int, int>(1, 2);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << printable(foo());
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c0dae362920f2525)

---

Of course, you could also just enable the printing directly for an `std::pair`...

```
template<typename CharT, typename A, typename B>
std::basic_ostream<CharT>& operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharT>& out, const std::pair<A, B>& pair) {
    out << pair.first << ' ' << pair.second;
    return out;
}

// (...)

std::cout << foo(); // And this would work just fine
```

... but I don't really recommend it, specially on a header, since you would be basically changing behavior of standard types and your colleagues (or yourself, in the future) may be confused by it.